# Position Absolute doesn't center block

Tags: html, css, block

I want my block to be at the center of the page, but after I set `position: absolute`, `margin-left` and `margin-right`, `auto` doesn't work.

```
.block1 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height: 336px;
  width: 1020px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Is it possible to have position :absolute and center the block at the same time?

Comment: Centered horizontally or vertically or both?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have fixed width, use, `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -halfWidth`.

```css
.parent-block {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: blue dotted 1px;
}

.block1 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-block">
  <div class="block1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Just set the `left` and `right` on this div to 0 like so:

```
.block1 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 336px;
  width: 1020px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic way:

```css
.block1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 336px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1"><div>
```